Is it a good idea to do a Master's project which is a new collaboration between two labs?
I am discussing starting a Master's project that would be a totally new project and most likely a collaboration - the collaboration may be negotiated solely based on my project at the initiative of lab A (not discussed with lab B yet).
It would be in service of a fundamental science lab (A) but the majority of the project would need expertise from another, more clinical lab (B) to use a more advanced biological model.
So I'd be building a model using expertise and cells from lab B but to use for the research of lab A. What should I discuss with both labs? I'm worried that if I do end up spending time in lab B because of practicality I'd be seen as an "outsider" and on the reverse if I am set up in lab A that I wouldn't have access to enough advice and supervision from lab B.
I'm also wondering if the question of who would supervise me may cause conflict or one of the two labs to be less interested in helping me achieve my project.
How should I go about this and discuss these worries?

My 2c worth (and I don't know enough to post this as an answer) is that lab A (being your "home" lab, if I read this correctly) should know how to go about setting up a collaboration with another lab, B. They may well have experience in doing that, and have some "rules of engagement" in place to set up and manage such collaborations. (It's not clear if the labs are in the same institution, which may have a bearing on how lab A would engage with lab B.) So, to me it seems clear: talk to lab A about this, and get them to set it up. OR.... why not just do the project in lab B in the first place?
